# How to print an asterisk cross based on an input number in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to draw a cross asterisk pattern with java based on a number entered, but I fail to move the upper and bottom part of the it to the middle.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=n*3; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Here is my result for n = 2:

```
**
**
******
******
**
**
```

Here is what I need to get:

```
  **
  **
******
******
  **
  **
```

Comment: HINT: Print **blanks** in front of things that need to be moved farther to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  The first is the more "traditional" way with nested loops.  Methods were created to avoid duplication of code.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
int n = scan.nextInt();

topBottom(n);
middle(n);
topBottom(n);

    
public static void middle(int n) {
    // print n lines of n*3 asterisks
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n * 3; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
    
public static void topBottom(int n) {
   
    // prints n lines
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // this loop prints n spaces
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // followed by n asterisks
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But you can do it with just three print statements and the `String.repeat()` method introduced in Java 11.

```
System.out.print((" ".repeat(n) + "*".repeat(n)+"\n").repeat(n));
System.out.print(("*".repeat(3*n)+"\n").repeat(n));
System.out.print((" ".repeat(n) + "*".repeat(n)+"\n").repeat(n));
```

And lastly, you can write your own repeat method using any version of Java. here is one using streams.

```
System.out.print(repeat(repeat(" ",n)+repeat("*", n)+"\n",n));
System.out.print(repeat(repeat("*",3*n)+"\n",n));
System.out.print(repeat(repeat(" ",n)+repeat("*", n)+"\n",n));

public static String repeat(String s, int count) {
    count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
    return Stream.generate(()->s).limit(count).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

For `n = 3`, they all print the following:

```
   ***
   ***
   ***
*********
*********
*********
   ***
   ***
   ***
```